# ios not showing image from VCF file

Tags: ios, iphone, vcf-vcard

i have a vcf file v3 that with image inside and when i download it form ios it doesnt show the image attached to it.

this is the file (i deleted most of the image data it was over 500000 chars, maybe its the problem?:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
REV:2018-03-16T00:44:58Z
N;CHARSET=utf-8:firstname lastname;;;;
FN;CHARSET=utf-8:firstname lastname
EMAIL;INTERNET:firstnamelastname@gmail.com
TEL:6314649333
ADR;WORK;POSTAL;CHARSET=utf-8:blabla address;;;;;;
URL:http://www.website.com
PHOTO;ENCODING=b;TYPE=JPEG:/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/7QCcUGhvdG9zaG9wID
 MuMAA4QklNBAQAAAAAAIAcAmcAFGdPdFp5S3ZpQ25FNTZ1MVk1dmluHAIoAGJGQk1EMDEwMDB
 hOWMwZDAwMDBjNzk2MDAwMGY2NDIwMTAwYjA1MDAxMDBjMjYxMDEwMDViZmQwMTAwMzMxMDAz
 MDBhODM0MDMwMGE2NGQwMzAwMmI2YTAzMDA2NjRkMDUwMP/iC/hJQ0NfUFJPRklMRQABAQAAC
 PNzuaWJwC7heFmBLspcurC+8Ohqk5/wCAnoXxihB6GujLi2z030eh14nHov1PRqb630uvTfRl
 S+nN9GHS4I9NQzNYh0//2Q==
END:VCARD
```

Comment: What code are you using to display the image? Can you post that code here?